# Table records display on the bases of enter number in textbox power bi

Tags: expression, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, qliksense

I have a table in power bi

in that there are so many records so i want a text box or something like that where use type number then on the bases of this records should be displayed in table e.g if we use type 5 then only 5 records will display.. if user type 10 then 10 record will display if there is nothing then all records should be displayed

how i should do this .. i know how to do in qliksense but not in power bi

and one thing more i want to apply that condition in field Cover Name

```
=if(Assured_Name = 'AFPY','AF',
if(COVER_NAME = '7co','ABC',
if(match(COVER_NAME,'AFPY','7CO')=0,'Other',null())))
```

Here there power bi sample file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kfym4mb0fiaxym5/Claims2.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The PowerBI equivalent of a 'control' that the user interacts with to filter a visual is the 'Slicer.'  The slicer can then be configured to enable a 'Search' textbox where the user can type in the desired text that is wanted for filtering the table.

Create a slicer visual next to your table and add the column that you want to search to the slicer's "Field" box.  Then, hoover your mouse over the slicer and a group of icons will appear (usually at the top but sometimes beneath the visual if there's no space to put it).  One of these is the ellipsis, it looks like 3 dots.  Click on the ellipsis and enable 'Search.'

You will see that a row is created in the slicer where the user can type. This text will filter the contents of the slicer, which is then used to filter the table.

Comment: @Ryab will you please create sample ?